# How can I obtain a list of the physical quantities supported?

Tags: physics, units

How can we list all available physical quantities in Mathematica?

Comment: I believe this is a different issue, since I don't want to list the units associated with the quantities, but the names of the quantities instead.

Comment: What do you believe the difference is? The list are the names. Or have I missed something?

Comment: The code provided on the linked question yields a list of units, not the quantities they are related to. It's different because the physical quantities names describe the nature of what's being measured in opposition to the units, which are the standards of measure.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [`UnitDimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitDimensions.html), correct?

Comment: Not essentially, because those are only base dimensions. I'd like to have derived physical quantities also.

Comment: May you add an example of what you are expecting the output to be for a particular input.  I'm not following what it is you are seeking. The unit name is what is passed to [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) to create `Quantity` objects; `Quantity[1, "Feet"]`, and `UnitDimensions["Feet"]` tells you that `"Feet"` is a unit of length.  So ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50759/discussion-between-fred-and-edmund).

Comment: Retracted close vote as OP is looking to get a list of all `QuantityVariable`'s in *Mathematica*.  For example, those supported by but not limited to `"QuantityVariablePhysicalQuantities"` property of `FormulaData`.

Answer (score 3):

Evaluate the following:

```
Quantity; (*only needed to establish symbol Quantity in symbol table*)
canonicalUnits = Keys @ QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules;
```

`canonicalUnits` is a big list. In V11.0.1

```
Length @ canonicalUnits
```

gives 4959. It contains more than just physical quantities. Here is a sample.

```
SeedRandom[42]; 
RandomSample[canonicalUnits, 20]
```

> `{"PlotterUnits", "AmagatDensityUnit", "Semimonthly", "Orguias", 
>   "Kiloleagues", "BrakeHorsepower", "Millioersteds", "Gigahenries", 
>   "BarrelsOfOil", "LinearInches", "RomanLibras", "LaoAtt", "Virgates", 
>   "Ris", "MegatonsOfOilEquivalentIT", "BritishMaunds", 
>   "LoschmidtConstant", "Coulombs", "Nanowatts", "Marks"}`

Comment: Actually, I was looking for the names of the quantities, not the units, e.g., "Time", "Lenght", etc..

Comment: @Fred. "Time", "Length", etc. are just strings. They have no supported special meaning in Mathematica.

Comment: But aren't they recongnized by `QuantityVariable` ? On documentation: "Supported physical quantities include both physical and chemical quantities such as "Length", "ElectricCurrent", and "ChemicalPotential", as well as mathematical and financial quantities such as "Angle" and "Money"."

Comment: When I type in free form input: `magnetic flux`, the output is a `QuantityVariable`